# PHP Contact Form Not Working - Please advise

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I am working on developing an HTML contact form for a site that executes a PHP code file upon click of Submit.  The problem that I am having is that the PHP script is displaying "message failed to send."  I have previously used this exact PHP file in another site, so perhaps the problem is with the HTML page.  Please provide any suggestions.

HTML - contact.html (Header not included)

```
<body>

<header>
  <img src="images/Banner" />
</header>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="badges.html">Badges</a></li>
<li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
<li><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>        
</nav>

<article>
<div id="pagebanner"><div id="bannertext"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Page Banner" --  >CONTACT ME<!-- InstanceEndEditable --></div></div><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Page Content" --  >
<div id="pageintro">If you need to contact me, please use one of the following ways.</div>
<div class="bodytextbold" style="text-align: left;">EMAIL</div>
<div class="bodytext" style="text-align: left;">Please complete the following form and click Submit to send me a message.</div><form id="contactform" method="post" action="contact.php">
  <p>
    <label for="textfield">Name:</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="35">
    <label for="textfield2">    </label>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="25">
    <label for="textfield2"><br>
      Subject:</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="textarea">Message:</label></p>
  <p>
    <textarea name="message" cols="75" rows="15" id="message"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Clear">
  </p>
</form>
<div class="bodytext">THANK YOU FOR YOUR MESSAGE.  YOU WILL RECEIVE A RESPONSE SOON!</div>
<div class="bodytextbold" style="text-align: left;">PHONE</div>
<div class="bodytext" style="text-align: left;">You may call me at <span style="font-weight:  bold";>(number)</span> any time between 5 PM and 9 PM.</div>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
</article>

<footer>

<div style="margin: 0 0 15px 0;"><a href="index.html">Home</a> | <a  href="badges.html">Badges</a> | <a href="news.html">News</a> | <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a> |   <a href="bio.html">Bio</a> | <a href="contact.html">Contact</a></div>
Copyright &copy; 2014 Paradimensional Entertainment
</footer>
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

PHP - contact.php

```
<body>
<?php 
$to = "someone@email.com"; 
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ; 
$name= $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ; 
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ; 
$headers = "From: $name, $email" ; 
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ; 
if($sent) {
echo ('Your message was successfully sent.');}
else {
echo ('Your message failed to send.  Please try again.');}
?>
```

Comment: Make sure your server has a mail server installed. You can't use the `mail()` function without that.

Comment: I am pretty sure they do.  I have used the same server before and I had no issues.

Comment: it's likely a server configuration issue. If mail() is returning false that means PHP is failing to send the mail, but if you're getting that error the form is probably working correctly. Add var_dump($_REQUEST); to see that the data is getting to PHP correctly, but I don't see any reason it wouldn't be.

Comment: just do `mail('youremail@domain.com', 'test', 'test');` and see if it sends. if it does, then remove the `$headers` and send again using your code. If that works, then you know it's something your headers. If it doesn't, then `mail()` doesn't work. Also could be bad data in your `$_REQUEST`. `var_dump()` like Lenny said...

Answer (score 0):

HTML - contact.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Form Contact</title>
  </head>
  <body> 
   <header>
    <img src="images/Banner" />
   </header>
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="badges.html">Badges</a></li>
     <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
     <li><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
     <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
     <li><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>        
   </nav>

   <article>
    <div id="pagebanner">
     <div id="bannertext">
      <div id="pageintro">If you need to contact me, please use one of the following ways.</div>
      <div class="bodytextbold" style="text-align: left;">EMAIL</div>
      <div class="bodytext" style="text-align: left;">Please complete the following form and click Submit to send me a message.</div>
       <form id="contactform" method="post" action="contact.php">
        <p>
         <label for="textfield">Name:</label>
         <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="35">
         <label for="textfield2">    </label>
         <label for="email">Email:</label>
         <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="25">
         <label for="textfield2"><br>Subject:</label>
         <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject">
        </p>
        <p>
         <label for="textarea">Message:</label>
        </p>
        <p>
         <textarea name="message" cols="75" rows="15" id="message"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
         <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Clear">
        </p>
       </form>

       <div class="bodytext">THANK YOU FOR YOUR MESSAGE.  YOU WILL RECEIVE A RESPONSE SOON!</div>
       <div class="bodytextbold" style="text-align: left;">PHONE</div>
       <div class="bodytext" style="text-align: left;">You may call me at <span style="font-weight:  bold";>(number)</span> any time between 5 PM and 9 PM.</div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </article>
  <footer>
   <div style="margin: 0 0 15px 0;">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a> | <a  href="badges.html">Badges</a> | <a href="news.html">News</a> | <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a> |  <a href="bio.html">Bio</a> |     <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
   </div>
   Copyright &copy; 2014 Paradimensional Entertainment
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

PHP - contact.php

```
 <?php 
  echo $_POST['name'];
  echo " - ";
  echo $_POST['email'];
  echo " - ";
  echo $_POST['message'];

  $to = "someone@email.com"; 
  $subject = $_POST['subject'] ; 
  $name= $_POST['name'] ;
  $email = $_POST['email'] ; 
  $message = $_POST['message'] ; 
  $headers = "From: $name, $email" ; 
  $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ; 
  if($sent) {
    echo ('Your message was successfully sent.');}
  else {
   echo ('Your message failed to send.  Please try again.');}
 ?>
```